# AngularJS Array Comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have got the following array of Usernames

```
Usernames = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "Jack",
    "description": "jack is a nice guy",
    "userRoleIds": [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "Caroline",
    "description": "Good girl",
    "userRoleIds": [
      2,3
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userName": "Smith",
    "description": "Smithyyyy",
    "userRoleIds": [
      1,2
    ]
  }
]
```

And an array of userRoles.

```
userRoles = [
  {
    id: 1,
    roleName: "Admin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    roleName: "Tester"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    roleName: "Developer"
  }
]
```

What i want to get done is first concat the arrays in in Usernames and userRoles to get the following result.

```
 Usernames = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "Jack",
        "description": "jack is a nice guy",
        "userRoleIds": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "roleName" : "Admin"
          }
        ]
      },
     {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "Caroline",
    "description": "Good girl",
    "userRoleIds": [
         {
            "id": 2,
            "roleName" : "Tester"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "roleName" : "Developer"
          }
    ]
   },...
```

The second thing i want is to be able to filter for the `roleName` and `userName` seperated by pipe signs. As in type something in a text box that searches for userName and roleName for example.

if i type

`Caroline, Tester`

The result will be

```
result = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "Caroline",
    "description": "Good girl",
    "userRoleIds": [
      2,3
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userName": "Smith",
    "description": "Smithyyyy",
    "userRoleIds": [
      1,2
    ]
  }
]
```

What is the best practice for achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. I prefer using services and take advantage of their functions to keep code clean.

```
app.service('UserService', function (PermisionsServices) {
    var self = {
        'list': [],
        'load': function (Users) {//Pass your array of Users
            angular.forEach(Users, function (user) {
                angular.forEach(user.userRoleIds, function (role) {
                    self.user.userRolesIds.push(PermisionsServices.get(role));
                });
                self.list.push(user);
            });
        }, 'get': function (id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.list.length; i++) {
                var obj = self.list[i];
                if (obj.id == id) {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return self;
});

app.service('PermisionsServices', function () {
    var self = {
        'list': [],
        'load': function (permisions) {//Pass your array of permisions
            angular.forEach(permisions, function (permision) {
                self.list.push(permision);
            });
        }, 'get': function (id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.list.length; i++) {
                var obj = self.list[i];
                if (obj.id == id) {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return self;
});
```

Afterwards, you can use it on your controller:
$scope.users=UserService;

And access each of the users as a separate object which can have multiple object permisions.

NOTE: Building the service (populating it) will of course depend on your app logic and controller, you could just easily remove the "load" function and just hardcode the list object by copy and pasting your arrays.

This is the approach I use to load data from API via resource.

Regards

Edit:
For use on the UI, you would just call:

```
<div ng-repeat='user in users.list'>
  {{user.name}} has {{user.permissions}}
</div>
```

as the object information is already contained within it.

Edit 2:
If you want to search your data, then you can just add a filter like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='user in users.list | filter: filterList'>
      {{user.name}} has {{user.permissions}}
</div>
```

And then on the controller:

```
$scope.filterList = function (user) {
        if ($scope.filterTextBox) {
            return user.name.indexOf($scope.filterTextBox) == 0;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Hi Pablo it will be all in the controller and i will display the result in the UI. cheers

Comment: questions confusions and queries are supposed to be asked in comments. @pablo

Comment: Looks pretty clean will create a plunkr and share it when done, will take me a while though i am not that good with js :)

Comment: No problem. Share the Plunkr when done and I can help you achive this really quick.

Comment: But what if i want to search for userName, userRole in the UI and display the appropriate results like in the last example of the question? Will have to add a filter in the controller?

Comment: The best practice would be to add a filter, as you want your services to have all the (relevant) data for your app. According to my experience services should only be used to interact directly with the data, while searches should be performed thru filters. Take this for example, lets say that you load your data from an API, and you perform a search inside the service, then everytime you search you would consume data from the server. Ill post the way I handle filtering so that you can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would do with pure JS like this. It won't take more than a single assignment line each.

```js
var Usernames = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "Jack",
    "description": "jack is a nice guy",
    "userRoleIds": [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "Caroline",
    "description": "Good girl",
    "userRoleIds": [
      2,3
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userName": "Smith",
    "description": "Smithyyyy",
    "userRoleIds": [
      1,2
    ]
  }
],
userRoles = [
  {
    id: 1,
    roleName: "Admin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    roleName: "Tester"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    roleName: "Developer"
  }
],
modified = Usernames.reduce((p,c) => (c.userRoleIds = c.userRoleIds.map(e => e = userRoles.find(f => f.id == e)),p.concat(c)),[]),
   query = ["Caroline","Tester"],
filtered = modified.filter(f => query.includes(f.userName) || f.userRoleIds.some(e => query.includes(e.roleName)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(modified,null,2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered,null,2));
```

Comment: i loved your vanilla solution except that it will not be supported by IE due to `find()`

Comment: @user3052526 Thank you. You are right with your concerns, yet i believe these shouldn't stop you from utilizing modern coding techniues. About older browsers you may chose to insert a polyfill like `Array.prototype.find || (Array.prototype.find = apFindShim);` Here how it looks like https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#find) to achieve this.

```
var role = _.find(userRoles, function(role) { 
            return role.roleName == 'Tester'; 
        });
_.find(Usernames, function(user) { 
    return user.userName == 'Caroline' || _.indexOf(user.userRoleIds, role.id)>=0; 
});
```